Query, unique and transpose issues on Gsheets
I have an issue I cannot figure out how to fix.
I have 2 columns, one with names and one with homework done.



Names
Homework




Person 1
Homework 1


Person 1
Homework 2


Person 1
Homework 3


Person 2
Homework 2


Person 3
Homework 2


Person 3
Homework 3



The data are coming from a query and updating every day from another sheet
What I am trying to achive is the following:



Unique names
Homework transposed col B
Homework transposed colC
Homework transposed colD




Person 1
Homework 1
Homework 2
Homework 3


Person 2
Homework 2




Person 3
Homework 2
Homework 3




I tried

=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2)))

But it gives me the following and it is not an array so I have to pull the formula every time there are new data



Names
Homework transposed col B
Homework transposed colC
Homework transposed colD




Person 1
Homework 1
Homework 2
Homework 3


Person 1
Homework 1
Homework 2
Homework 3


Person 1
Homework 1
Homework 2
Homework 3


Person 2
Homework 2




Person 3
Homework 2
Homework 3



Person 3
Homework 2
Homework 3




Any idea how to fix this?

You may use HSTACK() with MAP() dunction. Try-
=LET(x,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(z,TOROW(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=z),1)))))


